# Appcode not run on real device - it says its lock, even when i disabled the lock

Tags: ios, xcode, appcode, app-code

when i tried to run the project, i get a message:

"AppCode cannot launch applications on the device as it is currently locked with a passcode. Please unlock the device"

I disable the device, restart app code and it's still happened.

i can run the same project from Xcode and it works.

thanks

Comment: I was getting the same issue. Disconnecting the device and reconnecting again while unlocked resolved it.

Comment: it works! thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Amit your the man!!